# Calcular orientación entre 2 localidades (Lat/Lng) en Android con Maps API

Tags: google-maps, android

Necesito calcular la orientación entre 2 localidades(LatLng) en android, por ejemplo tengo 2 puntos(LatLng) en el mapa y trace una línea entre ellos (Polyline), lo que quiero es que el mapa quede orientado según esa línea, es decir que la línea quede visualmente vertical respecto a la pantalla. Sería calcular los grados que tengo que despues pasarle a CameraPosition para que ponga la orientación deseada.
Aclarando un poco mas lo que quiero obtener son los grados que tiene esa linea respecto al norte, es decir si la linea va del este al oeste entonces seria 90°

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar mover la cámara al área que se desea visualizar entre los dos puntos para que se visualice completo a lo que CameraUpdateFactory ajustaría automáticamente la visualización para verla completa. Su implementación es sencilla como se detalla en la [documentación de Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views?hl=es#como_configurar_limites).

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
// Create a LatLngBounds that includes Australia.
private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(
  new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));

// Set the camera to the greatest possible zoom level that includes the
// bounds
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AUSTRALIA, 0));
```

Comment: Y tambien ajustaria la orientacion de forma que queda vertical respecto a la pantalla del movil? por ej tengo el mapa orientado hacia el Norte, si agrego 2 ptos que serian de los cuales trazo la polyline, uno en el este y otro en el oeste del mapa, con este code se orienta el mapa digamos de este a oeste, nose si explico bien.